# Read JSON files created by gensim from Wikipedia dump

Tags: json, gensim, wikipedia

Problem in reading the JSON dumps created from Wikipedia Dump using gensim

I am trying to follow the instructions given on this link to read wiki dump and create JSON file.

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/scripts/segment_wiki.html

But the code is failing.

The code I am running is given below

```
from gensim import utils
import json

 # iterate over the plain text data we just created
with utils.open('D:\\enwiki-latest.json.gz', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
      # decode each JSON line into a Python dictionary object
      article = json.loads(line)

      # each article has a "title", a mapping of interlinks and a list of "section_titles" and
       # "section_texts".
    print("Article title: %s" % article['title'])
    print("Interlinks: %s" + article['interlinks'])
    for section_title, section_text in zip(article['section_titles'], article['section_texts']):
        print("Section text: %s" % section_text)

and the stack trace is as follows

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8b1125fd41d0> in <module>()
      3 
      4  # iterate over the plain text data we just created
----> 5 with utils.open('D:\\enwiki-latest.json.gz', 'rb') as f:
      6     for line in f:
      7       # decode each JSON line into a Python dictionary object

AttributeError: module 'gensim.utils' has no attribute 'open'
```

Please help me understand whats wrong with my code.

I am running in the code on a Windows 10 machine using Anaconda

Comment: What version of gensim have you installed?

Comment: the version is 3.7.3

Comment: It looks like `gensim.utils.open` was added just before the 3.8.0 release, so you're using example code that requires a later version.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, I used smart_open library and was able to read the file.